# Discord js 14 how to set default select menu when change

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

this is my select menu code

```
const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
.setAuthor({ name: name,iconURL:URL})
.setTitle(category.name)
.setImage(category.image)
.setTimestamp();

const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
  new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
    .setCustomId("select_product")
    .setPlaceholder("เลือกสินค้า")
    .addOptions(productList)
);
channel.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] });
```

I need to set StringSelectMenu To default always when change the dropdown list
when interaction reply confirm menu